# Stopping Background Processing (AsyncTask) when user leaves the application

Tags: android

I have developed an android 2.1 application. In that I am using AsyncTask for doing background processing. It gets the data from the WebService.

The Problem is : When I leave the application, the background service remains active only. 
When I go to Settings->Applications->Running Applications it shows me that the application is running. I have to forcestop that application.

Is there any way to stop the background tasks automatically when user leaves the application ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has a cancel method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean) )

Invoke it when your Activity is going to stopped (`onStop`) state, or maybe paused - `onPause` depending on your needs, see Activity lifecycle for further explanation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: The method onStop worked for me..First I have overriden onDestroy and in that i had called AsyncTask.cancel(true)...Thanks...

Comment: did calling AsyncTask.cancel(true) in onDestory() create any problems for you ?

Comment: When should one prefer onPause to onDestroy for stopping asynctask? In my apps I used to stop them in onPause, but what about when the user comes back?